# Error en pantalla completa con enlace de Mega en iframe: no funciona la pantalla completa ni el botón para subir el volumen, pero sí el de pausa

Tags: html, google-sites

Al importar un video de mega a Google Sites a través de un código HTML, este se importa correctamente, pero no funciona la pantalla completa ni el botón para subir el volumen pero sí el de pausa. ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

-(ejemplo del código utilizado)

```
<iframe src="https://mega.nz/embed/xxx" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: ¿Revisaste los atributos de [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)?